# Parse Nested XML Attributes with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am new to XML, I need to parse this part of a .XML page:

```
<TEAMDATA>
<Team TriCode="BOU" ShortName="Bournemouth" LongName="AFC Bournemouth" OfficialName="AFC Bournemouth" ID="t91" Manager="Manager" Venue="Vitality Stadium"/>
<Team TriCode="ARS" ShortName="Arsenal" LongName="Arsenal" OfficialName="Arsenal" ID="t3" Manager="Manager" Venue="Emirates Stadium"/>
<Team TriCode="AVL" ShortName="Aston Villa" LongName="Aston Villa" OfficialName="Aston Villa" ID="t7" Manager="Caretaker Manager" Venue="Villa Park"/>
<Team TriCode="BUR" ShortName="Burnley" LongName="Burnley" OfficialName="Burnley" ID="t90" Manager="Manager" Venue="Turf Moor"/>
```

My idea is to have the tricode, shortname and logname  for each team printed, ex.:

```
BOU Bournemouth AFC Bournemouth
ARS Arsenal AFC Bournemouth
...
```

This is the code I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strURL = "http://MyURL.xml";
        XDocument xDoc;
        string title = "";

        xDoc = XDocument.Load(strURL);
        var TeamID = from r in xDoc.Descendants("TEAMDATA")

                     select new
                     {

                         TriCode = r.Attribute("TriCode").Value,
                         ShortName = r.Element("ShortName").Value,
                         LongName = r.Element("LongName").Value,
                     };

        foreach (var r in TeamID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r.TriCode + r.ShortName + r.LongName);
        }
    }
```

Until now I receive the

> NullReferenceException exception

after the select new clause. What do I need to parse those lines?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 from r in xDoc.Descendants("Team")
                 select new
                 {

                     TriCode = r.Attribute("TriCode").Value,
                     ShortName = r.Attribute("ShortName").Value,
                     LongName = r.Attribute("LongName").Value,
                 };
```

What is wrong with your code?

`xDoc.Descendants("TEAMDATA")` returns all those descendants with element name `TEAMDATA` and that element doesn't have any of the attributes you are looking for.

`r.Element("ShortName").Value` this must be a typo. What you want was attribute value, but not element itself.

Comment: Still I have the An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred ..Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This is the most common error and I usually find the cause immediately, In this case I cannot find any.